# Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Show that for $gN \in G/N$, $(gN)^k = g^kN$ for all $k \in \Bbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Show that for $gN \in G/N$, $(gN)^k = g^kN$ for all $k \in \Bbb Z$.

I was instructed to use induction for this, but it doesn’t seem neccessary? Isn’t the binary operation on the quotient group defined as $gN \cdot hN=ghN$? If so then $$(gN)^k = gNgNgN \underset{k \text{ times}}\dots = g^kN$$

by definition?

Comment: Maybe it's a definition for $k=2$ and they want you to generalize, especially for negative $k$?

Answer (score 1):

If you take $gNhN=ghN$ for granted, then it is very easy. I guess the question wants you to show that $gNgN=g^2N$ from first principles, not assuming the result above.

We have $$gNgN=\{gn_1gn_2\ |\ n_1,n_2\in N\}=\{g(gn'_1g^{-1})gn_2\ |\ n'_1,n_2\in N\}=\{g^2n'_1n_2\ |\ n_1',n_2\in N\}=g^2N\ .$$

I'm sure you can take it from there by induction.